# AWS s3 bucket video is not playing in safari browser (in flutter web app) using laravel APIs

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, safari

Here is my code to upload file:

[image]

this code is for set headers to the files in order to display it in browser: (according to it's extension):

[image]

and see this also :

[image]

I tried to set different kind of headers; same like Chrome but still in Safari browser our flutter web app's video is not playing...this issues is not occurring in chrome.

Should I  pass any extra headers in my code?

Because in flutter webapp (in Safari browser) even video uploading and playing both are not working.

Should I apply any changes in AWS S3 account?

My APIs are in laravel